# Need to omit an regex pattern inside another regex expression

Tags: html, regex, tags

I want to make an expression which matches all the HTML tags except the anchor tag

```
<a href="something">
```

I want it to match all the other tags like `p`, `ul`, `li`, etc.

```
<p>asdasdasd</p>
<p sdasdsad><a href="asdasdasd"> AAAA</a></p>
```

should become

```
asdasdasd
<a href="asdasdasd"> AAAA</a>
```

Comment: `<p>asdasdasd</p>`
`<p sdasdsad>< a href "asdasdasd"> AAAA</a></p>`

should become

`asdasdasd`
`< a href "asdasdasd"> AAAA</a>`

Comment: I have demonstrated in an edit, how to make code better visible. Please [edit] your question to add the information from the comment; and maybe explain what it should mean...

Comment: Processing html (or xml) with regexes is very likely to turn into a frustrating experience. I recommend to use a dedicated tool.

Comment: In case you wonder, you probably got downvotes (not by me) for not showing any attempt of your own while not even having taken the [tour].

Comment: Also, questions just asking for a solution by listing requirements are usually considered off-topic as being too broad - and impolite towards people using their time to help with understanding and solving problems - not to do programming work for free.

Comment: I am really sorry. I am new to posting questions here.

Comment: It is fine, consider deleting your question while reading through the help pages. Maybe you can edit it towards the rules and undelete it later. Otherwise the downvotes will be an obstacle for your participation here.

Comment: I was thinking the same, of deleting it.

Answer (score 1):

to match any tag

```
<[^>]*>
```

to match a tag except those starting with `a`, using a negative look ahead

```
<(?!a )[^>]*>
```

to not match closing tag adding optionnal '/' and word boundary instead of space

```
<(?!\/?a\b)[^>]*>
```

Comment: Thank you.
<(?!a )[^>]*> using this would match everything except the one with the anchor tags. How should I proceed, if I do not want to match the closing </a> tags too? Should I use a "|"?

Comment: this is the last expression i've separated them to make easier to understand

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It has been most understanding.

Comment: negative lookahead (?!..), like other lookarounds are 0 length matches also `\b` which matches a non alpha character followed by alpha character or an alpha character followed by a non alpha;  and `^`, `$`